# Is it necessary to check definition of a macro in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am reading some C code and found preprocessors like this appear pretty frequently:

```c
#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)
        minimum = 0x0,
#else
        minimum = 0x1,
#endif
```

I am wondering that, compared to `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT`, does it have any advantages, or just a coding style?

In my view, no matter whether `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is 1, 0, or undefined, `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is always equivalent to `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)`.

Comment: `#if` is equivalent of `#if defined(X) && (x != 0)`. Not exactly `== 1`. In short, you have to write `#if X` and the result will be like `#if defined(X) && (x != 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

> In my view, no matter whether `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is 1, 0, or undefined, `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is always equivalent to `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)`

So test it!

```
#define ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT 2
#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT
#error apparently I am mistaken
#endif
```

The original matches only if `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is defined as `1`. Your version allows it to be any value other than zero.

Comment: What about `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1`?

Comment: Defining `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` to be 2 is not a test of the assertion that whether it is 1, 0, or undefined, `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is equivalent to `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)`.

Comment: That's true, but I think it's worth pointing out that OP's version is excessively brittle in the face of unexpected values.

Answer (score 2):

That specific code could be rewritten as `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1`. It can not be rewritten as `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` like you claim, since that would return `1` no matter the value, as long as `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is defined (and not zero).

In general, programmers tend to avoid `#if` checks infavour of `ifdef`/`#if defined` since the former silently evaluates to 0 in case the operator isn't defined. For example:

```
#if APPLES == ORANGES
  #error Apples are oranges
#endif
```

This makes an incorrect conclusion if neither identifier is defined.

Comment: @nielsen Yes. I added a note about that.

Answer (score 2):

From the [C programming language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf), 6.10.3:

> Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> - `#if` constant-expression new-line *groupopt*
> - `#elif` constant-expression new-line *groupopt*
>
> check whether the controlling constant expression **evaluates to nonzero**.

and 6.10.4:

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
> identical to keywords) **are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

Emphasis mine.

Your question:

> In my view, no matter whether `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is 1, 0, or undefined, `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is always equivalent to `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)`.

These are not equivalent, as `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` tests for any non-zero value, whereas `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)` specifically tests for 1.
It is the case that the latter could be shortened to `#if (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)`.

Answer (score 2):

> In my view, no matter whether `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is 1, 0, or undefined, `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` is always equivalent to `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)`.

This is a fact, not merely a view, as we can demonstrate by evaluating all the possibilities:

| `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` | `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` | `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | true |
| 0 | false | false |
| undefined | false | false |

However, outside the options you list, they differ:

| `ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` | `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT` | `#if defined(ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT) && (ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT==1)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | true | false |

> I am wondering that, compared to `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT`, does it have any advantages, or just a coding style?

In the absence of any studies of the rate at which humans make mistakes with one or the other, whether one has advantages over the other is largely a matter of opinion and conjecture. Generally, shorter or simpler code is favored if it is not unnecessarily obtuse. Unless there is some reason to treat definitions other than undefined, 0, and 1 as false, the former performs the desired function and is simpler and shorter.

If there is some reason to treat other definitions as false, then `#if ZERO_MIN_SUPPORT == 1` performs that and is simpler and shorter than the original code.